# Angular Get Selected CheckBoxes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, checkboxlist

I have a list of dynamically filled checkboxes using angular.

```
 <div ng-repeat="X in XList">
     <label>{{X.Header}}</label>
     <input type="checkbox" name="X" value="{{X.Item.Id}}" />
     <p>{{X.Header}}</p>
 </div>
```

I want a method to retrieve a list of all the selected checkboxes. 
Usually I'd use

```
 $('input[name=checkboxlist]:checked').each(function()
{
}
```

But this is not acceptable with angular .... So is there an appropriate Method to do so?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

here is the implemented [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/B5MGv1?p=preview)

```
 <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selected[record.Id]"> {{record.Id}}

 $scope.ShowSelected = function() {
  console.log($scope.selected);
  alert(JSON.stringify($scope.selected));
};
```

Comment: It's awesome, but when I check one of the checkboxes, This message occur: Error: can't convert undefined to object

Comment: i'm not getting what you are trying to say, can you elaborate in which condition you are getting error ? i do not see any error while selecting checkboxes.

Comment: Yes, at your code it works great, but when I added the "ng-model = selected[]" at my code, when I try to select one of the checkboxes, I receive that error.

Comment: Can you update your code in your question or make a plunker or fiddle just for a clear understanding

Comment: i can just make out you must be missing to write $scope.selected = {}; in the beginning of controller

Comment: I'm sorry, There is something that I can't understand. 
Why does the Selected appear as Id : State, If I want to select the first selected element for example, how can I do it ?

Comment: the selected appears as Id : state because of this preparation ng-model="selected[RQuestion.Id]" in check box and as far as selecting first selected is considered you have to do it in bit different way i have made plunker here http://plnkr.co/edit/Fbth4FMpssCHcODRJEgx?p=preview hope it helps you!.....

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't show results, it displays The $scope.selected as an empty list, & the id : undefined.

Comment: this is not working answer because when you uncheck check box it will remain in collection .

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ng-model` directive to directly bind a property to the element.

e.g.

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="X.Item.Id" />
```

This will update your model.

From this you will be able just to check the values within your model and see which are checked.

e.g.

```
angular.forEach($scope.yourModelItems, function(item){
    // item.value ? 0 : 1;
});
```

Check out the documentation for [ngModel](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angModel). Also the ToDo list example on the [angularjs.org](http://angularjs.org/) homepage demonstrates this.

p.s. On a side note, you can also make your angular directives html5 friendly by adding `data-` before. e.g. `data-ng-model="X.Item.Id"`

Comment: Thanks a lot , would it be possible if you mentioned the checking method ?

Comment: You would need to post the code of your model so I could see the values.

Comment: How is yourModelItems populated?

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in numbers" >
<td><input type="checkbox"  ng-model="selected[x.id]"></td>`<tr ng-repeat="x in numbers" >
```

then button for action

```
 <button ng-click="get_all_cheked()">Get checked</button>
```

and then in controller

```
 $scope.selected = {};
 $scope.get_all_cheked=function () {
 console.log("click");
 console.log($scope.selected);
 }
```