# Angular 4 component get selected checkbox

Tags: javascript, angular

I am new to Angular, and I want to get the current selected checkbox id. I have checked other threads in SO, but most of them are using with Controller, I am using in component.
Here is detailed information.
I have such a component

```
<table class='table table-striped table-hover admin-form' *ngIf="deviceCategories">
<a (click)="test()">test</a>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td class="text-center">序列</td>
        <th class="text-center">组名</th>
        <th class="text-center">LOGO</th>
        <th class="text-center">操作</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let deviceCategory of deviceCategories | paginate: config">
        <td class="center">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selected[deviceCategory.id]" id="checkbox_{{deviceCategory.id}}">
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">{{deviceCategory.id}}</td>
        <td class="text-center">{{deviceCategory.name}}</td>
        <td class="text-center"><img src="{{deviceCategory.logoUrl}}" width="30" alt=""></td>
        <td class="text-center project-actions">
            <a [routerLink]="['/management/deviceCategory/edit/',deviceCategory.id]" class="btn btn-white btn-xs text-muted"> <i class="fa fa-eye text-system"></i> 修改 </a>
            <a (click)="OnDelete(deviceCategory.id)" class="btn btn-white btn-xs text-muted"> <i class="fa fa-eye text-system"></i> 删除 </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

And here is my ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { PaginationInstance } from 'ng2-pagination';
import { DeviceCategoryService}from '../../../services/deviceCategory.service';
import { DeviceCategoryViewModel } from "../../../model/deviceCategory";


@Component({
  selector: 'app-device-category-admin-table',
  templateUrl: './device-category-admin-table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./device-category-admin-table.component.css'],
  providers:[DeviceCategoryService]
})
export class DeviceCategoryAdminTableComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() deviceCategories :any;
  @Input() config:any;

  public selected:{}

  constructor(
    private deviceCategorySvc:DeviceCategoryService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }  

  OnDelete(id:number){
      this.deviceCategorySvc.deleteDeviceCategory(id).subscribe(result=>{
          if(result.ok)
          {
            this.deviceCategorySvc.currentCategorys().subscribe(result=>{
              this.deviceCategories=result.data as DeviceCategoryViewModel[];
            });

          }

      });
  }
  test(){
    var result=this.selected;
      console.log(result);
  }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: where is the checkbox

Comment: thanks, I have added it now, I want to get the selected deviceCategory.id or deviceCategory

Comment: as a sidenote: you are also using `ng-model` which AngularJS syntax, perhaps check your code that you are actually not using AngularJS syntax elsewhere...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the suggestion from @Sajeetharan, I could achieve my requirement by below code.

html

```
   <td class="text-center">
        <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="deviceCategory.checked" />
    </td>
```

model for deviceCategory

```
 export interface DeviceCategoryViewModel {
        id?: number;
        name?: string;
        checked?:boolean;
    }
```

ts code to get the current checked boxes.

```
  console.log(this.deviceCategories.filter(d=>d.checked===true));
```

Comment: I want to show some of them are already checked. but this doesn;t work

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **`[checked]`** property and bind a variable to it and it should be a boolean value

```
 <input type="checkbox"  [checked]="deviceCategory.checked"  id="checkbox_{{deviceCategory.id}}"
 />
```

To get the id , you can add a function on **`(change)="getDeviceID()"`**

```
 <input type="checkbox"  (change)="getDeviceID(deviceCategory)" [checked]="deviceCategory.checked"  id="checkbox_{{deviceCategory.id}}"
  />
```

and inside **`TS`**

```
 getDeviceID(device:any) {
      console.log(device.id);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, how could I get the this checked id in my ts file?

Comment: added a explanation

Comment: Thanks, I could understand I will need to define a array to store the selected id in getDeviceID method, previous, I could see demo which will filter the selected checkbox easily instead of this way. Is it possible achieve like this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18100629/angular-get-selected-checkboxes)

Comment: If so, how could I use below code in ts file? `$scope.ShowSelected = function() {
  console.log($scope.selected);
  alert(JSON.stringify($scope.selected));
};`, I want to achieve my requirement with this way, but I just do not know how to use it in my component.

Comment: $scope is used in angular1, with angular 2 you will just use this.selected.id

Comment: Sorry for my poor language in Angular, my current code is above, but the test method output undefined. I could not use `this.selected.id` for error id does not exist. A simple demo works under angular 2 is much appreciated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145790/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-edward).

Comment: Hi Sajeetharan, are you still in this discussion?